# Double integrals and area?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What does  $\displaystyle \iint_U \, dx \,dy$ describe, where $U$, say, is some region in, say, the $(x,y)$ plane?

Is it the net area of $U$ in the $(x,y)$ plane?

How about $\displaystyle \iint_U f \, dx \,dy$, for some (appropriate?) $f$.  Is the net area enclosed  by $U$ in $f$?

I'm confused by so many different types of integrals in multivariable calculus. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and yes.

For a subset $U$ of $\Bbb R^2$ we have $$\text{Area of $U$}=\iint_U dA$$
where $dA=dxdy$. This is because you're just integrating at height $1$ above all of $U$, so you get $1$ times the area of $U$.

Now if we throw in an integrable function $f:U\to\Bbb R$ then $$\text{Area below $f$ on $U$}=\iint_U f ~dA$$
This is because you're integrating over $U$ at a height of $f(x,y)$, which changes with $x$ and $y$.

Note: I use "area" under $f$, but this is really a 3D volume.

Comment: What is your definition of "Area below $f$ on $U$"?

Comment: See my edit. I was just trying to use the same word in both cases.

Comment: Ok, you use "area" as synonym of "region". Maybe "region" could be used in both cases with less ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks. Does it make sense to say that the reason the double integral gives the area straight away in this case is because the integral $U$ is in the same plane (so no need for splitting it etc), and presumably the integral would be positive, so no absolute value needed?

Comment: If you want a catch-all area/volume term, go with measure.

Comment: @user537566 are you referring to the $\iint_U dA$ calculation? The integral is certainly positive here because you're just integrating $1$ over all of $U$. It gives the area because of what I said: you're technically integrating the function $1$ over $U$, so you're integrating over $U$ at a height of $1$, so this gives the area. Essentially this is a special case of the $\iint_U f~dA$ calculation.

Comment: @Dave I'm referring to area below $f$ one. Should it say the net area?

Comment: @J.G. Sounds interesting (but advanced). Right now I'd say I don't have a clear distinction between volume and area, really.

Comment: $\iint_U f~dA$ is just the volume of the region enclosed by $f$ and the portion of $U$ in the plane. So if $f$ is below the $xy$-plane then you get a negative volume/area. I am using area mostly here, but really area is for 2D objects, such as $U$, and volume is used for 3D or higher dimensional objects, such as the region enclosed by $f$ and $U$.

Comment: I really appreciate your patience. This has clarified a lot. This touches on one of my other confusions. Does $\iint_U f \,dA = \iiint_U f\,DA' $ with $z=0$? It seems I wrongly understood triple integrals to be volume integrals, and double integrals as area integrals.

Comment: Having a triple integral $\iiint_U$ doesn't really make sense here since $U$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a definite integral of the form $\int f dx$ is an area under $y=f(x)$, $\int f dx dy$ is a volume under $z=f(x,\,y)$. The special case $f=1$ gives your first integral.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, integration and [Measure Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)) are quite synonymous, which can be explained in very simple terms. We can say that the **measure** of a set can be calculated as follows:
$$ \mu(A) = \int_A 1 dx$$

For instance, suppose we wanted to find the distance between two locations $a$ and $b$, we can represent this as $A = [a,b]$ then we would expect the measure (distance) of this set to be its length, $b-a$.
$$\mu(A)= \int_{a}^{b} 1~dx$$ 
$$~~~~~~~ = b - a$$
Now say a rectangle has one side with length $a$ and another of length $b$. We would expect the area to be $ab$. Note from the example before, the measure of $[a,b]$ is some $x\in \mathbb{R}$. So why not say one side of the rectangle is just some set $[c,d]$ and the other is another set $[e,f]$?

Then if $B= [c,d]\times[e,f]$, the area of the rectangle is 
\begin{align*}
\mu(B) &= \int_{c}^{d}  \int_{e}^{f} 1~dxdy\\
&= (d-c)\times(f-e) \\
\end{align*}

Hopefully this gives you an intuition of integration from another perspective? To get the area of the rectangle we are finding the measure (integral) in the $x$-plane first, and then in the $y$-plane second, which covers all of the set. Note triple integrals are used to calculate the volume of a $3$D object and so on.

Comment: Thanks. This is very interesting, and simpler than I'd expected.